# PHP overloading return by reference, update value in array

Tags: php, overloading

I have a class for session handling that uses object overloading for `__GET and __SET`, I've been having issues with arrays and read to assign get by reference, such as `&__GET`

The problem is I can't update the values.  For example, let's say I have this:

```
$session->item['one']['name']
```

I'd like to change it, by assigning it a new value; `$session->item['one']['name'] = 'new value'`   However, it doesn't change.

Any ideas how to work around this?  Below is the code, thank you!

```
class Session 
{

    private $_session = array();

    public function __construct()
    {

        if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
            session_start();
        }
        $this->_session = $_SESSION;
    }

    public function __isset($name)
    {
        return isset($this->_session[$name]);
    }

    public function __unset($name)
    {
        unset($_SESSION[$name]);
        unset($this->_session[$name]);
    } 

    public function &__get($name)
    {

        return $this->_session[$name];

    }

    public function __set($name, $val)
    {     
         $_SESSION[$name] = $val;
         $this->_session[$name] = $val;
    }

    public function getSession()
    {
        return (isset($this->_session)) ? $this->_session : false;
    }

    public function getSessionId()
    {
        return (isset($_SESSION)) ? session_id() : false;
    }


    public function destroy()
    {
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
        session_write_close();
        unset($this->_session);
    }

}
```

Comment: Not posting this as an answer because I have no clue if it matters with `$_SESSION`, but have you tried doing `$this->_session = &$_SESSION;` in your constructor instead of how you're setting it now?

Comment: No I haven't and I just did and it freakin' works!  Thank you! Please post as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your constructor, change `$this->_session = $_SESSION;` to `$this->_session = &$_SESSION;` so you're getting a reference to it inside of your class.

Comment: If you finish the session, the reference still exists, however, it's not a reference to the (then current) superglobal any longer. So this is not compatible if you start a session, close it, and then start a second one in the same request. Implementing `ArrayAccess` can help here.